# what's the class Hibernate uses internally to format SQL output?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

We know SQL output formatting can be enabled by set an attribute to true in XML configuration file when using Hibernate. And I want to know name of the class or classes Hibernate uses internally.

It is because I am working on an old project, the developers hard-coded SQL statements into DAO classes and crammed very complicated ones into a few lines, which makes them very hard to read and understand.

I can extract the original SQLs from `StringBuffer` or plain string concatenation structures, but I still need something to format them for me. It can be of low accuracy, but at least can recognize key words like `select, from, join, union` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface `org.hibernate.jdbc.util.Formatter` is implemented by the classes

- `org.hibernate.jdbc.util.BasicFormatterImpl` and
- `org.hibernate.jdbc.util.DDLFormatterImpl`

(at least in versions 3.3.0 through 4.3.6).

Comment: I can confirm it's used in 4.3.6 too ! BasicFormatterImpl for DML and Query while DDLFormatterImpl for DML.